# Getting color frame from kinect v2

Tags: c++, opencv, kinect

Hi I tried with getting data from kinect and display through the OpenCV.
The Kinect is getting on and the program failed at getting image format.. 
Am I missing anything .. Please explain.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Kinect.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <winerror.h>



#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


int main() {


    IColorFrameReader*      m_pColorFrameReader = nullptr;
    RGBQUAD*                m_pColorRGBX = nullptr;
    const int cColorWidth = 1920;
    const int cColorHeight = 1080;
    IKinectSensor * m_pKinectSensor  = nullptr;
    HRESULT hr;

    hr = GetDefaultKinectSensor(&m_pKinectSensor);

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        return hr;
    }

    if (m_pKinectSensor)
    {
        // Initialize the Kinect and get the color reader
        IColorFrameSource* pColorFrameSource = NULL;

        hr = m_pKinectSensor->Open();

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = m_pKinectSensor->get_ColorFrameSource(&pColorFrameSource);
        }

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = pColorFrameSource->OpenReader(&m_pColorFrameReader);

            if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
                cout << "Got Color frame reader \n";

            }
        }

        //SafeRelease(pColorFrameSource);
    }

    if (!m_pKinectSensor || FAILED(hr))
    {
        cout << "Major Eror";

    }

    Sleep(6000);
    ///////////////////////////////

    IColorFrame* pColorFrame;

    hr = m_pColorFrameReader->AcquireLatestFrame(&pColorFrame);

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        cout << "Got color frame: \n";
        INT64 nTime = 0;
        IFrameDescription* pFrameDescription = NULL;
        int nWidth = 0;
        int nHeight = 0;
        ColorImageFormat imageFormat = ColorImageFormat_None;
        UINT nBufferSize = 0;
        RGBQUAD *pBuffer = NULL;

        hr = pColorFrame->get_RelativeTime(&nTime);

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = pColorFrame->get_FrameDescription(&pFrameDescription);
            cout << "Frame Desc \n";
        }

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = pFrameDescription->get_Width(&nWidth);
            cout << "Frame width \n";
        }

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = pFrameDescription->get_Height(&nHeight);
            cout << "Frame Height \n";
        }

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = pColorFrame->get_RawColorImageFormat(&imageFormat);
            cout << "Frame Format \n";
        }

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            if (imageFormat == ColorImageFormat_Bgra)
            {
                hr = pColorFrame->AccessRawUnderlyingBuffer(&nBufferSize, reinterpret_cast<BYTE**>(&pBuffer));
                cout << "Frame color Format 1 \n";
            }
            else if (m_pColorRGBX)
            {
                pBuffer = m_pColorRGBX;
                nBufferSize = cColorWidth * cColorHeight * sizeof(RGBQUAD);
                hr = pColorFrame->CopyConvertedFrameDataToArray(nBufferSize, reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(pBuffer), ColorImageFormat_Bgra);
                cout << "Frame color Format 2 \n";
            }
            else
            {
                hr = E_FAIL;
            }
        }

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {

            cout << "Got color data from the kinect\n";

BYTE* bytepImage = reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(pBuffer));
Mat image = Mat(1080, 1920, CV_8UC4, reinterpret_cast<void*>(bytepImage));
imshow("win",image);


        }

        //SafeRelease(pFrameDescription);
    }

    //SafeRelease(pColorFrame);

    ////////////////////////    
    cout << "End of";
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

The program is working success upto getting Frame Height .. After that it is failing.

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue reason;

```
 RGBQUAD*                m_pColorRGBX = nullptr;
```

should be

```
RGBQUAD*                m_pColorRGBX = new RGBQUAD[1920*1080]
```

Thanks,

Comment: please accept your own answer if it answers your question so that the system knows it is answered.

Comment: @Micka It seems it takes two days for the permission.. Will do tmrw . Thanks :)